# Unable to Post the userId as a parameter using React-Ntive

Tags: react-native

[image]I want to get the user data and I want to post the userId through the Json Body But I got a response error 'Undefined variable: userId'. When I run through Postman it responds correctly with the userId parameter.Please check my code.

```
  componentDidMount() {

  fetch('https://barnightslive.com/bar-nights-api-v2/api/getMyProfile', {

   method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  //  body : formData
  body: JSON.stringify({
    userId: '50' ,
  })

  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log('response', responseJson)
    if (responseJson.status === "1") {

      ToastAndroid.show("Profile has been received successfully", ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }

    this.setState({
      dataSource: responseJson,
      isLoading: false
    })
    })
   .catch(error => console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you have to use async and await. 
Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

const fetchData = async () => {
   const res = await fetch('https://barnightslive.com/bar-nights-api-v2/api/getMyProfile', {

   method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  //  body : formData
  body: {
    userId: '50' ,
  }

   })
  const resData = await res.json();
  if (!resData.ok) {
    // if any error this line executes
  }
  console.log('response', resData)
    if (responseJson.status === "1") {

      ToastAndroid.show("Profile has been received successfully", ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }

    this.setState({
      dataSource: resData,
      isLoading: false
    })
}
```

Comment: can u send a screenshot

Comment: I have added a screenshot.Check it.

Comment: What have you updated in this code?. Because I get the same error

Comment: Now I updated the whole answer I have used async and await to fetch and POST Data